# Chemical Equation parsing

Tags: java, regex

I have to write a program that takes a user's chemical equation as an input, like NaCl2, and separate it out into individual elements and the number associated with them. Is there a way to parse through a string and pair the individual elements, like in NaCl2 into Na and Cl2?

Comment: Wouldn't the respective cation/anions turn into Na(-2) and Cl(-1). And handle extra ions accordingly. You could just hardcode the periodic table into a hashmap or something.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. My thoughts are that if one character is Uppercase, then that starts a new element, and if the one after that is lowercase, that is the end of the element, and if the character after that is a number, it pairs with that element too, except I haven't learned anyway that helps determine if a character is uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in a comment, checking whether letters are uppercase or lowercase is key to this problem. What you're looking for to solve this is the `Character.isUppercase()` method. Your code should iterate over the characters in the input String and pass each to this method. I wrote up this rough draft of a code to demonstrate it (and it also prints the output for you - how convenient!):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.print("Enter formula: ");
String formula = sc.next();
String s = "";

for (int i=0; i<formula.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(formula.charAt(i))) {
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
            elements.add(s);
        }
        s = "" + formula.charAt(i);
    } else {
        s += formula.charAt(i);
    }
}
elements.add(s);

for (int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(elements.get(i) + " ");
}

System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Ok. New info. I have to acquire the atomic mass of each element through a text file that I just finished writing out, and after that, I have to calculate the molecular weight and then output the compound and weight to a text file along with the users name. I can take their name using scanner I know, but I'm not sure how to read or write from and to a file? @BethanyLouise

Comment: You can use a FileWriter to write to a file. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html You'll need to make sure you close it with `close()` before exiting the program, or else the text file will just be empty. To read from a file, you can simply use a Scanner that reads from the file instead of from `System.in`. Whenever you're dealing with file operations, you also need to set up your program to throw an IOException or encase the relevant portion of code within a try-catch statement block; if you're using an IDE like Netbeans, it will prompt you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a number of ways. One of them is using regular expressions. In this case the expression looks for an uppercase character, followed optionally by a lower case character, followed optionally by a number.

```
Pattern elementPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Upper}\\p{Lower}?)(\\p{Digit}*)");
```

This can be used to find all the elements in the input:

```
Matcher elementMatcher = elementPattern.match(input);
while (elementMatcher.find()) {
    String element = elementMatcher.group(1);
    String count = elementMatcher.group(2);
    System.out.println("Element: " + element + " count: " + count);
}
```